# How to split string "a b MARK c" to [“a b ”, “MARK”, “ c”] by 'MARK' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to split string `"a b MARK c"` to `[“a b ”, “MARK”, “ c”]` by 'MARK' in Ruby

EDITED:

How to split string `"a b MARK1 MARK2 c"` to `[“a b ”, “MARK1”, " ", "MARK2", “ c”]` in Ruby

UPDATED:

Sorry, I missed the space between MARK1 and MARK2.
I want to split the string to array by marks, in this case means `MARK1` and `MARK2`. The partition method only can split one word and one time.

Comment: Where does the empty string between `"MARK1"` and `"MARK2"` come from?

Comment: Could you please edit the question to describe the rule that transforms the input into the output?  More examples might be good, too.  As it stands, we can't tell what it is you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use partition.

```
"a b MARK c".partition("MARK")
# => ["a b ", "MARK", " c"]
```

Comment: Unless of course the string needs to be literally split by `MARK`, you could also use `[A-Z]+` for a more regex approach.

Comment: Of course take care that this will split only once MARK appears. If you want to split more than 1 MARK you maybe need to do doing scan or split (and then add MARK)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, could you write a demo for multiple MARK and `"a b MARK1 MARK2 C"`.

Comment: This is an aproach.  "a b MARK c MARK dsadsa".gsub("MARK","$MARK$").split("$")